# Centered Differences Approximation for f'(x) in terms of f'''(x)

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I know I shouldn't copy-paste a textbook question, but it's been bugging me for a while because I cannot figure it out. It's from Gilbert Strang's Calculus (1991), Chapter 3.3., Problem 31, p. 111:

Substitute for $f(x + \Delta x)$ and $f(x - \Delta x)$ in the centered approximation $\frac{f(x + \Delta x) - f(x - \Delta x)}{2x}$ to get $f'(x)$ + error. Find the $\Delta x$ and $(\Delta x)^2$ in terms of this error. Test on $f(x)=x^3$ at $x = 0 $.

For the life of me, I can't figure out what substitutions I'm to make. The correct answer, according to the textbook solutions, is $0 \Delta x$ + $\frac13 f'''(x) (\Delta x)^2$. But how you get there -- especially to f''' -- beats me. Help!

Answer (score 1):

$$
\begin{aligned}
f(x+\Delta x) &= f(x)+\Delta x f'(x)+\frac{\Delta x^2}{2}f''(x)+\frac{\Delta x^3}{6}f'''(x)+O(\Delta x^4) \\
f(x-\Delta x) &= f(x)-\Delta x f'(x)+\frac{\Delta x^2}{2}f''(x)-\frac{\Delta x^3}{6}f'''(x)+O(\Delta x^4) \\
\implies \frac{f(x+\Delta x)-f(x-\Delta x)}{2\Delta x} &= f'(x)+\frac{\Delta x^2}{6}f'''(x)+O(\Delta x^3)
\end{aligned}
$$
The $\Delta x$ errors term is $0$ because each term with the same sign disappears when you subtract the two equations. As for why your textbook has a factor of $1/3$, either I missed something or it should say $1/3! = 1/6$.